# Regression problems in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am applying ML based regression techniques for developing prediction model for my experimental setup.

I applied various models : LR, Decision Tree and Random Forest.
I am getting 84% accuracy for RF model. I now want to improve this score with Keras DL mode.

Can anyone guide me for approaching regression based techniques using DL with Keras.

I used following model but accuracy could not go beyond 70%:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20,input_dim=5, activation='relu'))

#second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))

#output layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

#compile ANN
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

How can one apply DL for regression techniques.

Comment: You provide too little insights into your data, how does it look like? The decision about hyperparameters, the loss function and also the architecture depends on what you want to achieve and how your data looks like. Everyone here will need more information to help you. Additionally, there is a conceptual error. The accuracy metric is used in classification task but not in regression tasks.

Comment: Basically its an experiment where I have 5 varying parameters and the system provides a signal output.I am trying to model the system output with ML and DL. But I reached limits with ML using randomForests.

As u suggested I changed the metrics to mae and mse but still the R2 score is around 60% .  Any suggestions to improve it further?

Comment: You must know that DL doesn't always out perform ML, sometimes simple SVM or RandomForest might do better than an ANN, I would suggest that you use grid search and try to find the best hyperparameters for the RandomForest model you had or try other machine learning techniques rather than switching to DL.

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudYoussef . Yes it has been mentioned in many articles that ML may perform better then DL sometimes. It looks like this is the case.  I used GridSearch CV and maximum accuracy I got is of 84%. I just wanted to explore DL methods

Answer (score 0):

Here is both regression and classification, with Keras and TF.  The data set is available from the link at the end of this post.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")


# Classification with TensorFlow 2.0
cols = ['price', 'maint', 'doors', 'persons', 'lug_capacity', 'safety','output']
cars = pd.read_csv(r'C:/your_path/car_evaluation.csv', names=cols, header=None)

cars.head()

plot_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
plot_size [0] = 8
plot_size [1] = 6
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = plot_size


cars.output.value_counts().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%0.05f%%', colors=['lightblue', 'lightgreen', 'orange', 'pink'], explode=(0.05, 0.05, 0.05,0.05))


price = pd.get_dummies(cars.price, prefix='price')
maint = pd.get_dummies(cars.maint, prefix='maint')

doors = pd.get_dummies(cars.doors, prefix='doors')
persons = pd.get_dummies(cars.persons, prefix='persons')

lug_capacity = pd.get_dummies(cars.lug_capacity, prefix='lug_capacity')
safety = pd.get_dummies(cars.safety, prefix='safety')

labels = pd.get_dummies(cars.output, prefix='condition')

X = pd.concat([price, maint, doors, persons, lug_capacity, safety] , axis=1)


labels.head()

y = labels.values


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

#Model Training
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


input_layer = Input(shape=(X.shape[1],))
dense_layer_1 = Dense(15, activation='relu')(input_layer)
dense_layer_2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(dense_layer_1)
output = Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax')(dense_layer_2)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])


print(model.summary())


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=8, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)


score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)

print("Test Score:", score[0])
print("Test Accuracy:", score[1])


# Regression with TensorFlow 2.0

petrol_cons = pd.read_csv(r'C:/your_path/petrol_consumption.csv')

petrol_cons.head()

X = petrol_cons.iloc[:, 0:4].values
y = petrol_cons.iloc[:, 4].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)


input_layer = Input(shape=(X.shape[1],))
dense_layer_1 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(input_layer)
dense_layer_2 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(dense_layer_1)
dense_layer_3 = Dense(25, activation='relu')(dense_layer_2)
output = Dense(1)(dense_layer_3)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error" , optimizer="adam", metrics=["mean_squared_error"])


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=2, epochs=100, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)


from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

pred_train = model.predict(X_train)
print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train,pred_train)))

pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,pred)))

# path to dataset
# https://www.kaggle.com/elikplim/car-evaluation-data-set
```